# Benchmarking mysql on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, benchmarking

Mysql on linux has a useful pager command that allows you to run a command and just see the results of processing the query and not displaying the results in the console.

pager cat > /dev/null

251903 rows in set (49.25 sec)

Mysql on Windows is missing the pager command. Running the command on Windows including output takes 1 min 17.28 seconds (most of the time is spent outputting to command prompt). How can I just time how long it takes to perform the command in Windows. (I suppose I could write a simple python program!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to the following for performance comparisons:

```
select count(*) from ......
```

Comment: Thanks, obvious now you mention it!